# Positioning ImageView at x,y inside a smaller RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have spent days trying to get this to work, reading hundreds of related StackOverflow pages and implementing every possible suggested solution without success, including...

1) `view.scrollTo(gridX, gridY);`

2) `view.scrollBy(gridX,gridY);`

3)

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(1405, 1158);
        params.leftMargin = gridX;
        params.topMargin = gridY;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

4) Matrix manipulations...

5) I need my app to have a **min sdk of 8 / 2.2**, so I can't implement:

```
view.setScrollX(gridX);
view.setScrollY(gridY);
```

6) and more...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.madDucks.wheretheulami.madducks.UL_Map">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/infoBox"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:background="#000"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="infoBox"
android:paddingBottom="3sp"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_below="@+id/infoBox"
android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroller"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/mapLayer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ulmap"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:layout_height="1158dp"
android:layout_width="1405dp"
android:scrollX="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:src="@drawable/ulcampusmap"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<Button
android:id="@+id/changeDestination"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="#000"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="changeDestination"
android:paddingTop="4sp"
android:text="@string/changeDestination"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/viewMyLocation"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:background="#000"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="viewMyLocation"
android:paddingTop="4sp"
android:text="@string/myLocation"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_ul_map);

view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.map);
view.setImageResource(R.drawable.ulmap);
```

Why do none of these work? Surely most should even if some won't, but none do.

The closest I've managed is `view.scrollTo(gridX, gridY);` which puts any x,y input at topLeft 0,0 and the map is then clipped, with anything above or to the left of x,y being inaccessible.

Should I use another approach? I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use AbsoluteLayout and set xy position (AbsoluteLayout have properties for setting xy position )

And put your imageview inside it.